# FFT of Gaussian Pulse

Tags: matlab, gaussian

I'm trying to get Fourier transform of a gaussian pulse. Here's a sample code I found on the Internet.

```
fs=80; %sampling frequency
sigma=180;
t=-0.5:10/fs:0.5; %time base

variance=sigma^2;
x=1/(sqrt(2*pi*variance))*(exp(-t.^2/(2*variance)));
subplot(2,1,1)
plot(t,x,'b');
title(['Gaussian Pulse \sigma=', num2str(sigma),'s']);
xlabel('Time(s)');
ylabel('Amplitude');

L=length(x);
NFFT = 1024;
X = fftshift(fft(x,NFFT));
Pxx=X.*conj(X)/(NFFT*NFFT); %computing power with proper scaling
f = fs*(-NFFT/2:NFFT/2-1)/NFFT; %Frequency Vector

subplot(2,1,2)
plot(f,abs(X)/(L),'r');
title('Magnitude of FFT');
xlabel('Frequency (Hz)')
ylabel('Magnitude |X(f)|');
xlim([-10 10])
```

I need an explanation. Assume that I'm trying to get Fourier transform of 100 femtosecond gaussian pulse. How can I calculate the sampling frequency, sigma and t variables.

Answer (score -1):

http://www.gaussianwaves.com/2014/07/generating-basic-signals-gaussian-pulse-and-power-spectral-density-using-fft/

A gaussian pulse has infinite support so there's no such thing as a "100 femtosecond gaussian pulse", you can however have a gaussian pulse with a sigma of 100 femtoseconds which is probably what you want. For your sampling frequency, you probably want to choose something such that you actually capture interesting information about the pulse. Your sampling period hence be less than a sigma (the original code (not the one you posted) from the blog used sigma/8). As for t, if you want to capture most of the energy in the pulse, you need to go several sigmas to the left and right of 0 which is where the pulse is centered in time.